# Responsive cards laid out in a Grid

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to find the best possible way to create responsive grid layout using Layout XML in Android Studio.

Let me first explain the design.
As you can see below, I would like to develop an interface that will contain 10 cards.
As the size of device changes, I would like the cards to shrink in height and then respectively, the contest inside the cards should also shrink (based on constraints I can put for them).

[image]

So I made a few attempts.
First, I tried Constraint Layout (as described below).
This resulted in the cards height being defined by the content inside the cards, hence the card size did not change when viewed on smaller device.

[image]

Then I tried GridLayout.
Once again, this resulted in card size being determined by the content and the layout could not scale dynamically.

So, I am trying to find out what I might try next so that I can get the desired results.
Maybe using Cards is a bad idea?
Should I be using Linear Layout instead?
Are there any examples out there that I can refer?
or
Going with Different layouts for different resolutions is the option?

Too many questions at this point.

## UPDATE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/midGuide"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.50121653"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/l1_title"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/anton"
    android:paddingStart="0dp"
    android:text="1"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bestScoretext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
    android:text="Best Score"
    android:textAlignment="textEnd"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bestScore"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/bestScore" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bestScore"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
    android:text="1.9pt"
    android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="38sp"
    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/l1_title"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/l1c6"
    app:srcCompat="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator" />

<!-- Card 1 -->
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/l1c0"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/bgHome"
    app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp"
    app:cardMaxElevation="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/midGuide"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/l1_title"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/l1c2">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subLevel0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=".0"
            android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subScore0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="3.8pt"
            android:textColor="@color/yellow"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/c0Guide"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/subLevel0" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/subLevel0"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.81"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/c0Guide"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_1_0_icon" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/c0Guide"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="75dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="51dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


<!-- Card 2 -->
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

    android:id="@+id/l1c1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/bgHome"
    app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp"
    app:cardMaxElevation="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/midGuide"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/l1c0">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subLevel1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=".1"
            android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subScore1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="4.2pt"
            android:textColor="@color/yellow"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/subLevel1" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/subLevel1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.81"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/c1Guide"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_1_1_icon" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/c1Guide"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="75dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="51dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

<!-- Card 3 -->
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/l1c2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/bgHome"
    app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp"
    app:cardMaxElevation="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/midGuide"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/l1c0"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/l1c4">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subLevel2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=".2"
            android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subScore2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="3.8pt"
            android:textColor="@color/yellow"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/c2Guide"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/subLevel2" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/subLevel2"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.81"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/c2Guide"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_1_2_icon" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/c2Guide"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="75dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="51dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

<!-- Card 4 -->
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

    android:id="@+id/l1c3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/bgHome"
    app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp"
    app:cardMaxElevation="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/midGuide"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/l1c2">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subLevel3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=".3"
            android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subScore3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="4.2pt"
            android:textColor="@color/yellow"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/subLevel3" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/subLevel3"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.81"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/c3Guide"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_1_3_icon" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/c3Guide"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="75dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="51dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

<!-- Card 5 -->
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/l1c4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/bgHome"
    app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp"
    app:cardMaxElevation="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/midGuide"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/l1c2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/l1c6">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subLevel4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=".4"
            android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subScore4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="3.8pt"
            android:textColor="@color/yellow"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/c4Guide"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/subLevel4" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/subLevel4"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.81"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/c4Guide"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_1_0_icon" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/c4Guide"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="75dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="51dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

<!-- Card 6 -->
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

    android:id="@+id/l1c5"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/bgHome"
    app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp"
    app:cardMaxElevation="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/midGuide"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/l1c4">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subLevel5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=".5"
            android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subScore5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="4.2pt"
            android:textColor="@color/yellow"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/subLevel5" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/subLevel5"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.81"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/c5Guide"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_1_3_icon" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/c5Guide"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="75dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="51dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

<!-- Card 7 -->
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/l1c6"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/bgHome"
    app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp"
    app:cardMaxElevation="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/midGuide"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/l1c4"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/l1c8">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subLevel6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=".6"
            android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subScore6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="3.8pt"
            android:textColor="@color/yellow"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/c6Guide"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/subLevel6" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/subLevel6"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.81"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/c6Guide"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_1_0_icon" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/c6Guide"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="75dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="51dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

<!-- Card 8 -->
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

    android:id="@+id/l1c7"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/bgHome"
    app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp"
    app:cardMaxElevation="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/midGuide"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/l1c6">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subLevel7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=".7"
            android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subScore7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="4.2pt"
            android:textColor="@color/yellow"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/subLevel7" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/subLevel7"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.81"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/c5Guide"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_1_3_icon" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/c7Guide"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="75dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="51dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


<!-- Cards end -->

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
    android:id="@+id/barrier"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:barrierDirection="left" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting each card's width to `0dp` and just add margins around each card. This way, the width will expand horizontally and keep height at its minimum (`wrap_content`).

You can also check out [flexbox-layout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout).

Comment: That works, but then the card takes the height of the content. What I want is that card height should fit the screen and the content inside cards scales to fit the card constraints.

Comment: You can have each card connect to each other vertically (i.e. card1 connected to top of card2 AND card2 connected to bottom of card1). Then, set each card's height to `0dp` for automatic height adjustments. As for keeping each card's contents within the constraints, you should contain them in their own layout. For example: `<cardView><ConstraintLayout> ...content here </ConstraintLayout></cardView>`. Can you share your xml code?

Comment: Connecting cards vertically and setting the height to 0dp solved it.